# How to find an exact solution to the equation $e^{1/x}-2x-1=0$

Tags: calculus

I know how to find some interval for roots using the intermediate value theorem or getting closer to the roots with the bisection method, but is there a way to *actually* solve this equation?

Comment: For analytical methods compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870605/solve-ex-1-2x-with-numerical-or-analytical-methods). Also, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013855/how-to-solve-for-x-ex-e-x-0?rq=1).

Comment: The only way to "exactly" solve such an equation is to invent a new function whose definition is the solution.  Which is very unsatisfying.  Look up Lambert Omega function, e.g.

Comment: The Lambert-W function was established because it has some merit for a class of equations, but I am surprised that for this kind of equation, another such function was also invented. This does not make much sense. Such equations can only be solved numerically, the Lambert-W function can also be calculated only numerically.

Comment: @B.Goddard But you have to prove that it isn't possible to solve.

Comment: I think it is not very important to have the EXACT solution for such an equation anyway. For polynomials with degree $3$ and $4$ there are exact formulas for the roots , but they are nevertheless almost never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "actually solve" means solving [in closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}}-2x-1=0$$
$x\to\frac{1}{t}$:
$$te^t-2-t=0$$

We see, this equation is solvable neither by [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) nor by [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number):
[How can we show that $A(z,e^z)$ and $A(\ln (z),z)$ have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse)

$$te^t=2+t$$
$$\frac{t}{2+t}e^t=1$$

We see, this equation isn't solvable by elementary functions and [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). But it is solvable by elementary functions together with Generalized Lambert W.

$$t=W\left(^{\ \ 0}_{-2};1\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{W\left(^{\ \ 0}_{-2};1\right)}$$

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 2):

I will prove that $x$ is irrational. Add $2x+1$ to both sides:$$e^\frac{1}{x}=2x+1$$Then, raise both sides to the power of $x$: $$e=(2x+1)^x$$Since $e$ is a transcendental number, it couldn't be expressed by radicals and so $x$ is irrational. This means that it doesn't matter if we have a closed form expression or not, and an approximation is best. Turns out that this has two solutions, one approximately $-0.447$ and another approximately $0.943$. Cancel the $0.943$ solution since it $e^{0.943}+0.943>0$.

Comment: First, you should have $e=(2x+1)^x$. Second, the fact that $e$ is transcendental alone doesn't say anything about solvability (*unless* you ask for, say, rational $x$).

Comment: @metamorphy Is there a way to correctly show that does not have a closed form expression?

Comment: I don't understand how do you conclude there is no closed expression from here, can you elaborate?

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes I changed my answer.

Comment: @metamorphy I changed my answer, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: That $x$ isn't rational follows directly from Hermite's theorem by comparison of the left-hand side with the right-hand side of the first equation in Kamal Saleh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) result:

$$\sqrt[x]e-2x=1\implies x=-\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^nn!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^\frac nx\right|_{x=-\frac12}$$

[tested here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Be%5E%28y%5E%28-1%29%29-2y%2C10%5D%2Cy%3D-1%2F2%2Bsum%5B%281%2F2%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5Be%5E%28n%2Fx%29%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D%2Cx%3D-0.5). Now to expand $e^y$ as a series and take the $n$th derivative with [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower%5Bu%2Cv%5D):

$$x=-\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-k)^{(n-1)}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}2^{k-1}n^k}{n!k!} $$

Next, interchange sums and use the [confluent hypergeometric function $\,_1\text F_1(a;b;z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1F1%28n%2C+2%2C+-2+n%29):

$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(-1)^{(n-1)}\,_1\text F_1(n;2;-2n)}{\Gamma(n)}=-0.4466986177721\dots$$

The $(-1)^{(n-1)}=(-1)^n n!,n\in\Bbb N$. For an integral representation, [transform](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/16/01/01/) the $_1\text F_1(n,2,-2n)$, convert to a [Laguerre $\operatorname L_n(x)$ integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LaguerreLGeneral/07/01/01/0002/), and interchange it with the sum to get:

$$\boxed{\sqrt[x]e-2x=1\implies x=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,_1\text F_1(n;2;-2n)=\frac1{2e^2}-\frac12+\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it-2e^{it}-2}\ln\left(1-e^{-2\left(e^{it}+1\right)}-e^{-2e^{it}-it-2}\right)dt=x≈-0.446698617772146595\dots}$$

[**Shown**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+1%2F%282+e%5E2%29-1%2F2+%2B1%2F%282+pi%29+Nintegrate%5B%28e%5E%28-2+-+2+e%5E%28i+t%29%29+%281+%2B+e%5E%28i+t%29%29+log%28e%5E%28-2+-+2+e%5E%28i+t%29+-+i+t%29+%28-1+%2B+e%5E%282+%2B+2+e%5E%28i+t%29+%2B+i+t%29+-+e%5E%28i+t%29%29%29%29%2F%28+%281+%2B+e%5E%28-i+t%29%29+%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2pi%7D%5D) [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%281%2Fx%29-2x%2Cx%3D-sum%5B1F1%28n%2C+2%2C+-2+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C490%7D%5D). Can one find an expression for the second root at $x=0.9433158\dots$?